# Iterating through a list of tuples or names from a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, read

I have the following command in a linux script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "001 ARG1" "002 ARG2" "003 ARG3"
do
    set -- $i
    echo $1
    echo $2
done
```

001 and ARG1 are essentially tuples,

Is there a way to move those tuples into a text file which I can load instead into the forloop?
so many i would save a text file like this

```
ARG1
ARG2
ARG3
```

or

```
001 ARG1
002 ARG2
003 ARG3
```

And the script would be

```
for i in textfile.txt
do
    set -- $i
    echo $1
    echo $2
done
```

and get the same result?

also is there a way to make it so that the 001 002 is counted automatically? Like how in python one could set counter = 0 and counter+=1 and assign a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two space or tab separated words on each line in a file as in your second example of the input file:

```
while read -r word1 word2; do
    echo "$word1"
    echo "$word2"
done <textfile.txt
```

This would read the first word on each line into `$word1`, and the rest of the line into `$word2`.

The input for `read` is given by the input of the `while` compound command, which gets it from the file via a redirection.

The `-r` option to `read` stops it from interpreting `\` in any special way, would that character occur in the input.

With a single word per line and a counter:

```
counter=0
while read -r word; do
    counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
    echo "$counter"
    echo "$word"
done <textfile.txt
```

This would increment the counter by one in each iteration (for each line read from `textfile.txt`).

To get a zero-filled three-digit counter, output the counter using `printf` with a formatting string of `%.3d\n`:

```
printf '%.3d\n' "$counter"
```

... in place of `echo "$counter"`.

For a description of what `%.3d\n` means, see the documentation of the C library function `printf` (`man 3 printf`, the shell equivalent uses mainly the same format string).